# Create Persian calendar in add form of Laravel

Tags: php

I want to add date for projects in form. I used this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Finish time</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="finish_time" id="finish_time">
</div>
```

How can I create a Persian calendar?

Comment: here is a good js package: https://github.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a javascript package for persian date :  [here](https://github.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker) is a good one!

Code Sample:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/persianDatepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/persianDatepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Finish time</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="finish_time" 
        id="finish_time">
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#finish_time").persianDatepicker();       
    });
</script>
```

And use `type="text"` instead of `type="date"`

Comment: I give this error`Unresolved function or method persianDatepicker` when Add your code

Comment: you need `persianDatepicker.css`  , `jquery.min.js`, `persianDatepicker.min.js` to be loaded before your script: `$("#finish_time").persianDatepicker();`

Comment: I did All of them but  persian calendar don't open And form is just text form

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).persianDatepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (23:30)
    at c (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.q (jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4)
persianDatepicker.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158234/discussion-between-ahmad-mobaraki-and-hanie).

Comment: @hanie_asemi my telegram Id